Topology and structure sheaf on $\overline{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\cup\{\infty\}$
In
Deninger, Christopher, Local (L)-factors of motives and regularized determinants, Invent. Math. 107, No. 1, 135-150 (1992). ZBL0762.14015., p. 145, the author speaks of $\overline{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\cup\{\infty\}$ where $\infty$ is the (real) infinite place.
What is the topology on $\overline{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}$ and what does the structure sheaf look like?

The author says "we speculate on a global cohomological approach" so perhaps there is no precise formalization.

I don't know anything about this, but isn't there some Arakelov geometric way of understanding $\overline{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arakelov_theory
